# Sobre o rowspan

Tags: html

```
<p align="center">
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding"2">

            <tr><td colspan="2">Tabela de Caracteristicas</td></tr>

            <tr> **<td>rowspan="4"</td>** <td>Philips</td> <td align="center">Altura</td> <td>115,5 mm</td> 



        <!-- o rowspan não esta querendo funcionar aqui na td -->

        </tr>
        <tr> <td align="center">Largura</td> <td>90,45 mm</td></tr>
        <tr> <td align="center">Profundidade</td><td>5 cm</td></tr>
        <tr> <td align="center">Peso</td><td>400 gr</td> </tr>

        </table>    
    </p>
```

Eu não sei o que está faltando aqui para que a tabela e suas dimensões possam abrir um espaço a esquerda de 4 linhas para ficar como um cubo vazio com a palavra Philips, isso tomando o lugar de quatro linhas.

Preciso de ajuda.
Agradeço desde já, quem o puder me ajudar.

```html
<p align="center">
   <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding"2">
   
   <tr><td colspan="2">Tabela de Caracteristicas</td></tr>
   
   <tr> <td>rowspan=""</td> <td>Philips</td> <td align="center">Altura</td> <td>115,5 mm</td> 
   
   <!-- o rowspan não esta querendo funcionar aqui na td -->
   
   </tr>
   <tr> <td align="center">Largura</td> <td>90,45 mm</td></tr>
   <tr> <td align="center">Profundidade</td><td>5 cm</td></tr>
   <tr> <td align="center">Peso</td><td>400 gr</td> </tr>
   
   </table> 
  </p>
```

Comment: Posta o código pra ficar mais fácil de alguém te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Eles servem para indicar que um determinado **td** se expandirá por uma quantidade específica de linhas ("rowspan") ou colunas ("colspan") além do espaço que ela já ocuparia na tabela.

Por exemplo, "colspan=3" fará com que o **td** ocupe mais duas (1+2) o espaço de mais dois **td** à direita dele:

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>g</td><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Assim como "rowspan=3" o fará ocupar o espaço de três (1+2) **td** abaixo dele:

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=3>a</td>
        <td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>e</td><td>f</td><td>g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>g</td><td>h</td><td>i</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Eles ainda podem ser usados em conjunto para ocupar tanto o espaço à direita quanto o abaixo:

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ou seja, eles são análogos aos comandos de mesclar células nas planilhas eletrônicas e processadores de texto.

Comment: Grato! Compreendi. Mas especificamente para esse código, fazendo o teste dele, a tabela e as informações quando executado ficam fora, de locação. Então nesse, caso especifico é onde eu não estou compreendendo, o que eu errei, na hora de implementar o código, porque é que as informações ficam fora de alocação.

Comment: Lembre-se que você precisa descontar os **td** que você esticou das linhas e colunas vizinhas. Se você tem três colunas e fez "colspan=2" esta linha da tabela só deverá ter dois **td**.

Comment: Fico grato! Deus te abençoe.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente:

```
<p align="center">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding"2">
  <th colspan=3>Tabela de Caracteristicas</th>

  <tr>  
    <td rowspan=4>Philips</td>
    <td align="center">Altura</td>
    <td>115,5 mm</td> 
  </tr> 

  <tr>
    <td align="center">Largura</td>
    <td>90,45 mm</td> 
  </tr> 

  <tr> 
    <td align="center">Profundidade</td>
    <td>5 cm</td>
  </tr> 

  <tr>
    <td align="center">Peso</td>
    <td>400 gr</td>
  </tr> 
</table>    
</p>
```

Comment: Perfeito!!!!

Grato! Foi em cima da pinta.

Agora sim.

Comment: Eu identifiquei meu erro. Eu tinha que colocar um align para cada td.